# Is Silverlight technology is suitable for the described project

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I am going to develop one HRMS application which maitains companies account,marketing,hr and network department information it's functional implementation. Does silverlight is preferable to use with this kind of ERP application.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight would definitely be a possibility but it would require all users to install the Silverlight plugin.

Since you want to target corporate users, I would probably stick to ASP.NET (WebForms or MVC) if you want a web client and WPF if you want a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight would work; however this sounds like an application more suited for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

not really cause silverlight has not good connection to a back end Database like SQL , its a plugin like flash , you have to make a web services as a work arround for the lack of database connection support